# NSMutableDictionary setValue:/forKey:?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a `NSMutableArray` named animals. I need to create an `NSMutableDictionary` such that all names in the animals array have `Keys` that start with a specific first letter = `Values`.

This is animals array :

```
NSMutableArray *animals = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo", @"Camel", @"Cockatoo", @"Dog", @"Donkey", @"Emu", @"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea", @"Hippopotamus", @"Horse", @"Koala", @"Lion", @"Llama", @"Manatus", @"Meerkat", @"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear", @"Rhinoceros", @"Seagull", @"Tasmania Devil", @"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat", nil];
```

this is my code to set it into a `MutableDictionary` :

```
 for(NSString *str in animals) {
     NSString *firstLetter = [str substringToIndex:1];
     NSArray *newArr = [NSArray arrayWithObject:str];
     [myMutableDictionary setValue:newArr forKey:firstLetter];
 }
```

The problem is that for each key only one value is set, but i need all the objects have a first letter with the same value. E.g. value='b' -> @"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo".

Comment: Just to be clear... You just need the names grouped by their first letter or you need their first letter for something like indexing in a tableview?

Comment: For starters [NSDictionary setValue:forKey] doesn't work like you think it does. Review the docs on that. It will set a value for exactly one key, matching exactly that value. You will need to use something like NSPredicate to find all the values matching and get a subset array which you can copy into an NSDictionary.

Comment: @Alladinian like indexing in a tableview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
for (NSString *str in animals) {
    NSString *firstLetter = [str substringToIndex:1];
    if(!myMutableDictionary[firstLetter])
    {
        myMutableDictionary[firstLetter] = [NSMutableArray new];
    }
    NSMutableArray *arr = myMutableDictionary[firstLetter];
    [arr addObject:str];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. working perfectly , can you explain how exactly its working ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the code that satisfied your requirement.

Step 1 : Allocate `NSMutableDictionary`.

Step 2 : While parsing `NSArray`, check initial is there key available in `dictionary` or what. if available then that array from same key and add new element in `array` and update `same key` in `dictionary`. if not available then  create `new key` in `dictionary`. here is code.

```
NSMutableDictionary* dictTemp = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for (NSString *str in animals) {

    NSString *firstLetter = [str substringToIndex:1];

    if([[dictTemp allKeys] containsObject:firstLetter]){
        NSMutableArray* arrayInner = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[dictTemp valueForKey:firstLetter]];

        [arrayInner addObject:str];

        [dictTemp setValue:arrayInner forKey:firstLetter];

    }
    else{

        NSMutableArray* arrayInner = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [arrayInner addObject:str];
        [dictTemp setValue:arrayInner forKey:firstLetter];

    }


}

NSLog(@"Output : %@",dictTemp);
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.